# Encrypting data on application layer, on top of ssl

Tags: encryption, ssl, https

I am in the process of developing website and an app (iOS and Android) that are supposed to communicate data over https. I don't want the app clients intercepting these server messages, but I'd like to decrypt that data inside the app itelf. 
so: after request, encrypt message (say up to 400kb message) (1st encryption), send over https (ssl encryption) (2nd encryption). 
upon receive decrypt ssl, on the client level decrypt scrambled message.
(I don't want some bots sniffing my db through https, in disguise of my app).
How do you think I should get around this problem ?

https is ok, I mean, but if someone is sending the requests instead of the app, the whole thing would be useless as I want to protect the DB data.

Any suggestions ? ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need here is HTTPS/SSL with client authentication. Adding a second layer of encryption doesn't actually add any security. PKI authentication of the client does.

Answer (score 0):

SSL client authentication will help, as EJP said, but it requires your app to contain an embedded private key, and if someone really wants your data, they can analyze your app and extract that key.

This isn't something you can solve completely:  your server *cannot* reliably distinguish between the real client app, and a fake one designed by someone who reverse-engineered the real one to imitate it.

Depending on the app, you may be able to transfer some of the work to the server side.  In other words, don't expose the raw data to the app, just expose the parts that the app is allowed to display.  That way an attacker can't get anything by spoofing the app that they couldn't have gotten by just using the real one.

Answer (score 0):

I actually came up with the idea to encrypt the request rather then the response.
this way a user can't spoof and send requests to the db.
I just thought that doing the encryption again might be doing too much for too little.